# Google DataStudio : link parameters to control dropdown list

Tags: parameters, google-bigquery, looker-studio

In datastudio, is it possible to link the selection made in a dropdown control (let's the field customer_name in a list, **so this is a dynamic list, not an hardcoded one** !) with a parameter (let's say @param_customer_name).
So, when a user select a customer from the dropdown control, it fills the parameter @param_customer_name with the value selected, and then I can launch an sql query in BigQuery ?
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Here's the feature request in Google's issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/172592357

Answer (score 1):

Edit(based on update from OP): Data Studio currently (Sep 2021) does not support dynamically populating parameter value list.

---

Original:

1. When you create your parameter, permit **List of Values** and add all the values:
   [image]
2. Add the Drop-down list control and for the control field, select your parameter:
   [image]

This Drop-down list control will have the values that you added to your parameter and the selected parameter value will be available to the Data Source and can be used in your BigQuery query.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I was not clear : the Drop-down list must takes its values from a datasource, it should not be hardcoded. Do you if this can be achieved ?

Comment: Parameters controls current do not support dynamic values from a source.